# How this sentence is complete and correct? "I am going to go get dressed

Tags: grammar

I am confused of using "going to go" and "get dressed" together. Because "go" is verb, it should be followed by Objective. However, "get" is verb. So, this sentence have consecutive verbs. I cannot believe this sentence is grammatically possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In American English, "**Go do something**" is a common shortening of "**go *and* do something**." [See definition 1(c) in Longman Online.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/go)  It means that the action of the second verb isn't occurring where the conversation is happening.

For example:

- Standing in the kitchen, a parent might tell a child, "Go clean your room."
- Before leaving for the grocery store, a roommate might say, "I'm going to go buy milk. Is there anything you need?"

In the sentence in your example, the speaker is likely not in the room where they will dress, or not in the section of the room in which they will dress.

This construction where the "and" is dropped only occurs with "go" in the present tense. We wouldn't say "I went got dressed."

I don't think you were wondering about "going to go," but for thoroughness's sake, "going to" here is expressing intention about future action. "I will go get dressed" has the same meaning.

Comment: 'This construction where the "and" is dropped only occurs with "go" in the present tense.' – I would add that the construction only occurs where "go" and the other verb take their uninflected forms. People might say "after I go get dressed" and "after they go get dressed," but you'd never hear "after she goes gets dressed."

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You are a greatest teacher!